# Execution time in nano seconds and related issues

Tags: c, benchmarking

I am using the following code to compute execution time in milli-secs.

```
struct timespec tp;
 if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp) == 0)
  return ((tp.tv_sec * 1000000000) + tp.tv_nsec);
 else
  return ;
```

Can you please tell me whether this is correct? 
Let's name this function comptime_nano().

Now, I write the following code in main() to check execution times of following operations.

```
 unsigned long int a, b, s1, s3;
 a = (unsigned long int)(1) << 63;
 b = (unsigned long int)(1) << 63;
 btime = comptime_nano();
 s1 = b >> 30;
 atime = comptime_nano();
 printf ("Time =%ld for %lu\n", (atime - btime), s1);
 btime = comptime_nano();
 s3 = a >> 1;
 atime = comptime_nano();
 printf ("Time =%ld for %lu\n", (atime - btime), s3);
```

To my surprise, the first operation takes about roughly 4 times more time than the second. Again, if I change the relative ordering of these operations, the respective timings change drastically.

Please comment...

Comment: What, are you trying to measure the time it takes to perform a *single* shift?

Comment: +1 too harsh to neg vote, we all were beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clock_gettime` is not accurate enough for that kind of measurement. If you need to measure operations like that, do the operation several thousand (or several million times) in a loop before comparison. The two operations above should take the same amount of time but the second in your example code does not have the overhead of loading `a`, `b`, `s1`, and `s3` into the processor's cache.

Also, what's going on here?

```
struct timespec tp;
 if (clock_gettime (CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp) == 0)
  return ((tp.tv_sec * 1000000000) + tp.tv_nsec);
 else
  return ;
```

The first return is illegal if the function returns `void`, and the second is illegal if it does not return `void`....

EDIT: `1000000000` also overflows the range of `int`.

Comment: Are you sure about the resolution? The Linux docs say the resolution is system-dependent. I could easily see a system using RDTSC on an Intel platform to get a resoultion in CPU clocks (which should be sufficient). Also, the large integer shouldn't be an issue, as time values tend to work in 64-bit integers. The bare return *is* a problem though.

Comment: @T.E.D.: 1000000000 is a signed int. 1000000000 does not fit in a signed int. If you want 64 bit literals you need to do 1000000000ll or 1000000000ull. Even if the timer will give you time in CPU clocks, it's still not accurate enough. CPU clocks don't show the relative performance of two pieces of code; more often they are showing nothing but cache behavior in code like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your resolution isn't good enough, and you are running on an Intel PC, try using the realtime time-stamp counter (RDTSC). I found this code for using it on Umbutu:

```
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<time.h>
typedef unsigned long long ticks;

static __inline__ ticks getticks(void)
{
     unsigned a, d;
     asm("cpuid");
     asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));

     return (((ticks)a) | (((ticks)d) << 32));
}
```